# Calculate the distance between points and the start of each lines

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, distance

I am trying to calculate the distance between the green points and the red point on their left and add that distance to the green points attributes.

The lines are roads and I made the red dots using the QChainage extension. I then added the roads ID to the red dots. After that I tried to calculate the distance using the Distance Matrix but the results weren't the one I expected.

Is there another way I could get the distance between the points and the point to their left?

[image]

Comment: Do the green dots have an attribute field to identify the target red dot?

Comment: Yes, they have a unique ID in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions:

- `Red`: The layername of the red points
- `id`:  The unique id field in the `Red` layer.
- `Green`: The layername of the green points
- `red_id`: An identifier which suggests the point in `Red` layer. This corresponds to `id` in the `Red` layer.

Workflow:

1. Open attribute table of the `Green` layer and start the Field Calculator.
2. Create a new field `dist` (or something like that) with an expression `distance($geometry, geometry(get_feature('Red', 'id', "red_id")))`

Hope this helps. Please modify the attribute names as required.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I will just need to fix a few things with my red dots and I will have the results I needed